# Allocate multi dimensional array from a data file

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran

I have a file containing information about a multi-dimensional array. I have created a subroutine that reads the file and copies
the array data to an array variable. My problem is that I have to first allocate the dimensions of the array outside the subroutine first. Is there a way to allocate the array inside my subroutine as the array dimensions are also stored in the data file.

Currently I have the following code, where I first allocate the multi-dimensional array and then populate it by calling `selcs`.

```
Allocate (c3d(nu,nv,nw))
Call selcs (c3d, nm, cpht, rsl, st)
c3d = c3d * 2.0
Deallocate (c3d)
```

I would prefer to have the subroutine `selcs` itself allocate
the memory for `c3d` using dimensional information present in the file and then use the array outside `selcs` as before.

```
Call selcs (c3d, nm, cpht, rsl, st)
c3d = c3d * 2.0
Deallocate (c3d)
```

Comment: Yes (since F2003, or F95+TR15581) it's possible to have the dummy argument of the routine allocatable (corresponding to an allocatable effective argument).  But you know that, surely: I think I'm missing something important about your question.

Comment: What is the difference from using an allocate when the subroutine is a function returning a multi-dimensional array? Does it work the same way as a subroutine so I can also use it as shown and replacing the code with `c3d = selcs (c3d, nm, cpht, rsl, st)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern Fortran (since a technical report to Fortran 95, included in Fortran 2003) the dummy argument of a procedure may have the `allocatable` attribute.  It is then possible for the procedure to alter the allocation status of that dummy argument.

This requires that the actual/effective argument also has the `allocatable` attribute and any change to the allocation status of the dummy argument is reflected in the actual argument.  Array shape and values are retained after the call, as one would expect with other arguments.

So, it's entirely appropriate to leave the allocation of the array to the subroutine.  But some things to note:

- with an allocatable dummy argument, an explicit interface will be required in the referencing scope;
- a dummy argument with the `intent(out)` attribute will be deallocated on entry (and the actual argument, also);
- a dummy argument with the `intent(in)` or `intent(inout)` attribute will take initially the bounds/allocation status of the actual argument.