# Can I pass arrays with undefined dimension to a Fortran subroutine as INTENT(INOUT)?

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I need to pass arrays of variables to a subroutine that should change their values according to an external file. The problem is that this should be as generic as possible so if the file has n values I should be able to pass n generic integers.

Here is an example of my code:

```
program dummy
    
    use checkpt
    implicit none

    integer :: i1=0, i2=0, k=1, n, cpt
    integer*8 :: lastTime

    call load_checkpoint(ints=[k,i1,i2])
    
    --some code happening--

end program dummy
```

And the subroutine called is the following:

```
subroutine load_checkpoint(ints)
        implicit none

        integer, intent(inout) :: ints(:)
        integer :: stat

        open(8989, file='temp.txt', status='old', action='READ', iostat=stat)
        if (stat .eq. 0) then
            read (8989,*,iostat=stat) ints
        end if
        close(8989)

    end subroutine load_checkpoint
```

What I get is `Error: Non-variable expression in variable definition context (actual argument to INTENT = OUT/INOUT) at (1)` and I can't understand why. I also tried with non initialized variables but I get the same error. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: In your subroutine you use intent(inout) - this requires an array in the actual argument to do the "out" bit.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You aren't using g the value of the argument before you define it, so `intent(inout)` makes no sense, but to be defined in the procedure it needs to be a definable variable not an array expression. It's not obvious why you want to use `ints=[...]` instead of an actual variable, so some more detailed explanation of what you want to happen would help clarify.

Comment: But it certainly sounds like you want to use [an allocatable argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32223125/3157076) which is allocated around the file reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a dummy argument is `intent(out)` or `intent(inout)`, then the actual argument shall not be an expression. Your actual argument `[k,i1,i2]` is an expression (more precisely an array constuctor, that builds here a rank one array from 3 scalar variables), this is why you get an error here.

If you want your variables `k`, `i1` and `i2` to be updated at the end you have to write more lines (and in the called subroutine you should attribute only `intent(out)` to ints, as you don't use at all the input values):

```
integer :: ints(3)
call load_checkpoint(ints=ints)
k  = ints(1)
i1 = ints(2)
i2 = ints(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even return an allocatable array from a function.

Checking datafiles with arbitrary number of lines, arbitrary number of integers per line is a bit messy.

```
module checkpt
   implicit none

contains

   function load_checkpoint()
      integer, allocatable :: load_checkpoint(:)
      integer nvars, i
      integer stat
      character(len=1000) line

      open( 10, file="temp.txt", status="old", action="read", iostat=stat )
      if ( stat == 0 ) then
         ! First pass - count variables (arbitrary number per line, arbitrary number of lines)
         nvars = 0
         do
            read( 10, "( a )", iostat=stat ) line
            if ( stat /= 0 ) exit
            do i = 1, len_trim( line )
               if ( isdigit( line(i:i) ) .and. ( i == 1 .or. ( i > 1 .and. .not. isdigit( line(i-1:i-1) ) ) ) ) nvars = nvars + 1
            end do
         end do

         ! Second pass - store variables
         allocate( load_checkpoint( nvars ) )
         rewind( 10 )
         read( 10, *, iostat=stat ) load_checkpoint
      else
         write( *, * ) "Unable to read file"
         stop
      end if

      close( 10 )
    end function load_checkpoint


    logical function isdigit( c )
       character, intent(in) :: c
       isdigit = c >= '0' .and. c <= '9'
    end function isdigit

end module checkpt

!========================================================================

program dummy
   use checkpt
   implicit none
   integer, allocatable :: intvars(:)

   intvars = load_checkpoint()
    
   write( *, "( *( i0, 1x ) )" ) intvars
end program dummy
```